# Unable to setup a host name binding with an emoji (unicode 6 character) on IIS 8

Tags: hostname, iis-8

I'm trying to setup a host name of `xn--n68h.tk` on our IIS8 with an emoji (unicode 6 character). When I add it as a binding our IIS stops and when I try to start it I'm getting an "Value doesn't not fall within the expected range" error.

How do I patch our IIS8 to support this?

Comment: I've noticed this question has gotten "two down" votes. What could the reason be for this .. do I need to improve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else are looking for this I found the solution. I tried adding the URL as what's called "Punycode" e.g. instead of the "taxi" emoji I explicitly tried to add "xn--n68h".

IIS doesn't like this hence I got the error .. what you should do is simply add the URL as unicode and it will even display the emoji character correctly from within inetmgr.